# correct name for a method

Tags: c#, math, naming

I am struggling with a name for a method. The implementation is already done, I am just looking for a good name!

**potential candidates :**

- Segregation
- Extract
- Split

**The Method**

> IEnumerable< Period > GOODNAME (IEnumerable< Period > periodCollection)

!Period is a class with properties startdate and enddate!

**What should my function do:**

break the periodCollection into the smallest (and unique period) items as possible. Every change in Date gives a new periode item.

**Example**

periodCollection:

- Period (from=Monday, until=friday)
- Period (from=tuesday, until=thursday)

The result should be:

- Period (from=Monday, until=tuesday)
- Period (from=tuesday, until=thursday)
- Period (from=thursday, until=friday)

> **Who could suggest me a good naming for this Method?**

**From code the call lookes like**

var result = PeriodeCollection.GOODNAME();

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ would be better place for this I think.

Comment: Can you provide another example? Maybe one where your algorithm gets clear. The current example is as clear as mud I'm afraid.

Comment: you should name it **INCEPTION**

Comment: What is the difference between your input and your result?

Comment: @Azhar Khorasany : updated example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes your method names are very important within your code, however this shouldn't be something you ponder on for 10-15minutes, it should be quick to think of and easy to remember and relatable to your code. Over more it should be something that won't conflict with a future method. See the [MSDN Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4df752aw%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) on methods, as you can see it is short and sweet, therefore so should be the thinking of your method names. roll of the tongue if you would like.

I would suggest that you relate to your method with something like **PeriodNormalization** or any other example you can think of. This way it will be easy to understand

Comment: I used method name Segregate. Thank you all for discussing this with me

Answer (score 0):

I suggest "Decompose" or "Normalize".

Comment: I used method name Segregate. Thank you all for discussing this with me